# python batch gradient descent does not converge

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I have increased and decreased the learning rate and doesn't seem to converge or takes forever. 
if I set the learning rate to 0.0004 it slowly tries to converge but requires so many iteration I've had to set over 1mil+ iteration and only managed to go from 93 least squared error to 58

I am following Andrews NG forumla

Image of the graph with the gradient line:

[image: image of the graph with the gradient line]

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import time


data = pd.read_csv('weight-height.csv')
x = np.array(data['Height'])
y = np.array(data['Weight'])


plt.scatter(x, y, c='blue')
plt.suptitle('Male')
plt.xlabel('Height')
plt.ylabel('Weight')
total = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Total amount of data {}'.format(len(x)))
plt.legend(handles=[total])

theta0 = 0
theta1 = 0
learning_rate = 0.0004
epochs = 10000


# gradient = theta0 + theta1*X


def hypothesis(x):
    return theta0 + theta1 * x


def cost_function(x):
    return 1 / (2 * len(x)) * sum((hypothesis(x) - y) ** 2)

start = time.time()

for i in range(epochs):
    print(f'{i}/ {epochs}')
    theta0 = theta0 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum (hypothesis(x) - y)
    theta1 = theta1 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum((hypothesis(x) - y) * x)
    print('\ncost: {}\ntheta0: {},\ntheta1: {}'.format(cost_function(x), theta0, theta1))

end = time.time()

plt.plot(x, hypothesis(x), c= 'red')


print('\ncost: {}\ntheta0: {},\ntheta1: {}'.format(cost_function(x), theta0, theta1))

print('time finished at {} seconds'.format(end - start))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem might be that you are updating `theta0` and `theta1` one by one:

```
theta0 = theta0 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum (hypothesis(x) - y)
# the update to theta1 is now using the updated version of theta0
theta1 = theta1 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum((hypothesis(x) - y) * x)
```

it would be better to re-write such that the 'hypothesis' function is called once and explicitly pass it the values of theta0 and theta1 to use, rather than using global values.

```
# modify to explicitly pass theta0/1
def hypothesis(x, theta0, theta1):
    return theta0 + theta1 * x

# explicitly pass y
def cost_function(x, y, theta0, theta1):
    return 1 / (2 * len(x)) * sum((hypothesis(x, theta0, theta1) - y) ** 2)

for i in range(epochs):
    print(f'{i}/ {epochs}')
    # calculate hypothesis once
    delta = hypothesis(x, theta0, theta1)
    theta0 = theta0 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum (delta - y)
    theta1 = theta1 - learning_rate * 1/len(x) * sum((delta - y) * x)
    print('\ncost: {}\ntheta0: {},\ntheta1: {}'.format(cost_function(x, y, theta0, theta1))
```

Comment: wouldn't assigning the hypothesis function to delta always be called? as in it would always calculate based on the iteration. Also, with regards to updating theta0 and theta1, how would I even go about updating both simultaneously without using thread?  many thanks

I hav etried your solution and outcome still the same, i think it's to do with updating theta0 and theta1 as you suggested

Comment: Simultaneous update is possible in the code I suggest without using threads because we calculate the change to be made to each theta component based on the existing values of theta (the delta calculation) then modify the thetas.

Comment: I updated my answer, as I realised I had not correctly modified your `cost_function` function. It now has it's explicit dependence on theta0, theta1 called out.

Comment: If the function is still not converging correctly, maybe include a graph of the cost over time? Does that reduce consistently or is it still going wrong?

Comment: I'll see if I can get the graph over time.  
the cost does reduce [gif](https://i.imgur.com/bCdVy8q.gifv) but it's very minimal. same outcome as previous where it would require a lot of iteration.  when I increase the learning rate to let say 0.000001,  as opposed to 0.0004, I can see the cost reducing dramatically until it hits around 93. I presume this is hitting the local minimal point. When I use a different set of data [dataset2](https://i.imgur.com/gbcbcnW.png) it finds the minimal point but these data are diagonal instead of all over the place.

Comment: Hey Robert, many thanks for your help. looks like it is converging but at a local minimum, as opposed to global when I input an a value I get a rough estimate as displayed. thanks agian

Answer (score 0):

came back to say I managed to fix this by using feature scaling and mean normalization for it to converge a lot quickly as opposed to using the true value.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjgtP.png)